# Django foreign keys are not saving properly

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, foreign-keys

I have multiple foreign keys in the same model and for some reason, whenever I hit submit on the form, the last foreign key is overriding the previously entered ones. Can anyone see whats going on?

**models.py**

```
class Meal(models.Model):
    """
    Three of these will be given to a study
    """
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    start_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    stop_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Meals For Studies'

    def __str__(self):
        return "Meal Information for CRF # " + str(self.general_info.case_report_form_number)


class MotionStudyInstance(models.Model):
    # ###############ADD MEAL INFORMATION#######################
    meal_one = models.ForeignKey(Meal, related_name='first_meal', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    meal_two = models.ForeignKey(Meal, related_name='second_meal', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    meal_three = models.ForeignKey(Meal, related_name='third_meal', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Motion Studies Awaiting Validation'

    def __str__(self):
        return "CRF: #" + str(self.general_info.case_report_form_number)
```

**forms.py**

```
class MealForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Meal
```

**views.py**

```
class MotionStudyInstanceFormView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
        def post(self, request):
            if request.method == 'POST':
                    form = MotionStudyInstanceForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
                    meal_one_form = MealForm(request.POST)
                    meal_two_form = MealForm(request.POST)
                    meal_three_form = MealForm(request.POST)
                    if meal_one_form.is_valid() and meal_two_form.is_valid() and meal_three_form.is_valid():
                        meal_one = meal_one_form.save()
                        meal_two = meal_two_form.save()
                        meal_three = meal_three_form.save()
                        motion_study_instance_one = form.save(commit=False)
                        motion_study_instance_one.meal_one = meal_one
                        motion_study_instance_one.meal_two = meal_two
                        motion_study_instance_one.meal_three = meal_three
                        motion_study_instance_one.save()
                        return redirect('data:motion-studies')
            else:
                 form = MotionStudyInstanceForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

**motionstudyinstance_form.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <h1>Motion Study Form</h1>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% bootstrap_form form %}
        <p>Meal One Information</p>
        {% bootstrap_form meal_one_form %}
        <p>Meal Two Information</p>
        {% bootstrap_form meal_two_form %}
        <p>Meal Three Information</p>
        {% bootstrap_form meal_three_form %}
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

{% endblock %}}

Like i said, when I save the forms, the first two meal entries are overridden and look like copies of the third. What am I doing wrong? I am new to django.

Comment: isn't the same request.POST for the three forms?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You said "the first two meal entries are overridden and look like copies of the third" and I think the three forms will always have the same values because they receive the same request from request.POST

Comment: I have individual forms rendering for each meal though. How would I give a separate request for each one?

Comment: How do you submit these froms then ? one by one?. if so, you can change the action of each form. 
If you render their field data inside a single form, you can determine which form is submitted from field names in POST data

Comment: could you possibly provide a small example? Im really new to django so I am trying to grasp concepts like this early on

Comment: Edit your post with a form, I will do it with it quickly!

Comment: my apologies I misread your comment. Do you want me to post the template where I am rendering the forms? Now updated with html page that renders forms with request.POST

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why having the same form copied three times inside one html form. However the request.POST will always have the same values for each.
i.e: though you duplicated the form, the generated inputs by Django will have the same names.

```
description = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)

{{form.description}}
```

will generate

```
<input type="text" name="description" id="id_description" maxlength="256">
```

even copying {{form}} twice, the name remains description for each form.

so request.POST["description"] contains the last or first value received.

You may generate 3 forms in your template, with different actions followed a short get parameter.

```
<form action="/your_url/?form=1" method="post">
    {% bootstrap_form form %} <!-- the first form -->
    <!-- enter code here, with the submit button -->
</form>

<form action="/your_url/?form=2" method="post">
    {% bootstrap_form form %}<!-- the second form -->
    <!-- enter code here, with the submit button-->
</form>

<form action="/your_url/?form=3" method="post">
    {% bootstrap_form form %}<!-- the third form -->
    <!-- enter code here, with the submit button-->
</form>
```

You can also use a hidden input for each form, in order to know exactly which form is submitted

```
<form action="/your_url/" method="post">
    {% bootstrap_form form %}<!-- the second form -->
    <input type="hidden" name="form" value="3">
    <!-- enter code here, with the submit button-->
</form>
```

In your view:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MotionStudyInstanceForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    # If GET parameter
    w = request.GET.get("form","") # form 1 , 2 or 3
    # If Hidden Input
    # w = request.POST.get("form","")
    if w == "1":
        pass
```

Comment: My goal is to display the forms on the same page and submit them all with one submit button. The post method will then hook in the foreign keys in the backend. I get what you're saying about the POST['description'], but is there to do what you showed above and still render the forms on the same page with one submit button?

Comment: you can do so with: form1 = MotionStudyInstanceForm(), form2 = MotionStudyInstanceForm(), form3 = MotionStudyInstanceForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form1': form1,'form2':form2,'form3':form}). but in the templates, it will be redundant because each input field will have the same names through the 3 forms. explain what you want to do, It might be another way to do it instead of having 3 forms inside  triggered by the same submit button

Comment: Well my goal is to render multiple forms and then hook up the foreign key relationships in the backend. That way the user only sees one form and does not know what the backend is doing. Everything is working until I come to the three meal forms. If i can figure out a way to render the three meal forms and save them correctly then I will be on my way to finishing the site. The issue is that I do not know how to correctly save the three separate meal forms without any of them being overridden.

Comment: all I need to do is render the three meal forms simultaneously and save them correctly.

Comment: Is this the same form that you want to display 3 times, right?  You may display the form once and add those buttons: "SUBMIT" "SUBMIT & ADD OTHER", if the user chooses the 2nd options, you will redirect to the empty form (3 times max). To deal with the foreign key relationships. The best way is to create the Meal before, and after link the instance to the MotionStudyInstance model.  I don't see where exactly the user is linked to MotionStudyInstance BTW

Comment: Ok! if you are sure to deal with only 3 meal form. just render the form with pure HTML. <input type="text" name="description1" />  <input type="text" name="description2" />

Comment: I am certain that the user will always input exactly three meal forms. How exactly would I implement this pure html you mentioned? Would this solve my foreign key issue?

Answer (score 0):

The code below is not the best way to do it but If I understand what you wanna do, it will do the trick.

HTML : More validations needed here

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for i in 'aaa' %} <!-- A way to duplicate three times ,foorloop with make them different -->
    <input type="text" required name="description{{forloop.counter}}" id="id_description{{forloop.counter}}">
    <input type="date" required name="date{{forloop.counter}}" id="id_date{{forloop.counter}}">
    <input type="text" required name="start_time{{forloop.counter}}" id="id_start_time{{forloop.counter}}">
    <input type="text" required name="stop_time{{forloop.counter}}" id="id_stop_time{{forloop.counter}}">
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

VIEWS: More validations needed here as well

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    n = {"1":"one","2":"two","3":"three"}
    # Create The Instance of MotionStudyInstance
    motion_study = MotionStudyInstance.objects.create()
    for i in range(1,4):
        i = str(i) # in order to concatane with string
        date = request.POST.get("date"+i,"")
        start_time = request.POST.get("start_time"+i,"")
        stop_time = request.POST.get("stop_time"+i,"")
        description = request.POST.get("description"+i,"")

        # Test if everything is ok with each input fields

        m = Meal.objects.create(
            date = date ,
            start_time = start_time,
            stop_time = stop_time,
            description = description,
        )   
        eval("motion_study.meal_"+n[i]) = m

    # Finally save the instance
    motion_instance.save()
```

Comment: I will see what I can do and let you know if any problems occur. Thanks for all of the help!